# How to plot a sequence of short lines of specified colours

Tags: plotting

Further to my impasse with `ListVectorPlot` questions [155785](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155785/125) and [156025](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156025/125), I am trying to restart from basics. I have tried but couldn't find the right instructions. Sorry to have to ask.

Can anyone please write code to  plot a series of short lines from `(x,k*sin[x])` to `(x+.1*kx,ksin[x]+.1)` for `{x, -1.57, 1.57, .1}` and `{k, {.01, .2, .4, .6, 1}}` with according colors `{Red, Brown, Blue, Pink, Purple}`
Thank you very much.

Then I could use `Show` to combine this with a parametric plot of `(x,k*sin[x])` with the the same colors for the same k to achieve what I wanted `ListVectorPlot` to do, but it always mixed up the colours or the scaling of the short lines (representing vectors representing a complex function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
color[k_] := 
 Switch[k, 
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ (Flatten@
      Transpose[{{0.01, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1}, {Red, Brown, Blue, Pink, 
         Purple}}])]]

Graphics[Table[
  {color[k], Line[{{x, k*Sin[x]}, {x + 0.1*k*x, k*Sin[x] + 0.1}}]},
  {x, -1.57, 1.57, 0.1}, {k, {0.01, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1}}]]
```

[image]

With [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate@Table[{x, k*Sin[x]}, {k, {0.01, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1}}],
  {x, -1.57, 1.57},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Brown, Blue, Pink, Purple}],
 Graphics[Table[
   {color[k], Line[{{x, k*Sin[x]}, {x + 0.1*k*x, k*Sin[x] + 0.1}}]},
   {x, -1.57, 1.57, 0.1}, {k, {0.01, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1}}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: V. grateful for your two suggestions.The first worked beautifully on version 7 here but the second went awry, I couldn't change its strange graph which had dots instead of line segments for x>0 and nothing but the base curve for x<0. But it doesn't matter since the first way works here.

Comment: @simon - somehow in the cut and paste a comma got dropped. Try it now with the comma added back.

Comment: I found that in the end, I thought it was my computer's cut and paste error.I would have expected an error message from Mathematica. For the base graph I had Plot[Evaluate@Table[k*Sin[x],{k,{.01,.2,.4,.6,1}}],{x,-1.57,1.57},PlotStyle->{Red,Brown,Blue,Pink,Purple}]   which is a teeny bit simpler

Comment: I never would have figured out that Switch on my own in a miilion years